# Oracle SQL - Difference between AND & OR operators

Tags: sql, oracle

what is the difference between `AND` and `OR`Operators?

In the online class shows that `AND` displays a combination of 2 different conditions whats confusing is `OR` does the same thing, here is an example:

```
select employee_id , first_name,job_id,salary

FROM employees

where department_id = 10 

OR Department_ID = 20 

AND job_id in ('FT_MGR','AC_MGR');
```

Comment: `a and b` condition will be passed if both `a` and `b` are passed. `a or b` condition will be passed if either `a` or `b` is passed.
Also note that without parentheses `and` takes priority over `or`, so your query will return all employees with `department_id = 10` and only those employees with `department_id = 20` who have job_id 'FT_MGR' or 'AC_MGR'. In general the semantics is completely same with logical `AND` and `OR` operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND operator mean both (department_id = 10) is TRUE also (Department_ID = 20 ) is TRUE, result is TRUE

OR operator mean either (department_id = 10) is TRUE or (Department_ID = 20 ) is TRUE, result is TRUE